# Refreshing div (cause browse to redraw it)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, tabs

In a web application, I'm hitting some troubles with dynamic content - whereby a form being hidden or shown above a jQuery UI tab control causes rendering issues until the user hovers there mouse over the tabs, which then causes the tab header to redraw in the correct location.

It's only occurring in IE7 and as a quick hack I'm doing this after showing the form to cause the tab's div to be refreshed in IE:

```
$('#tabs').css('display', 'none').css('display', 'block');
```

I'm just wondering if there is a more appropriate/robust way to cause a `div` element to redraw itself/recalculate the layout of elements on a page, as I'm worried my approach may have unwanted side-effects on other browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue to this once, it turned out to be an issue with the width not being set on the displaying div.  When I set the static px width on the element it worked.

Comment: Yah, setting a width also sets hasLayout to true. http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html

Comment: That's a good resource - though I've come across snippets of articles on hasLayout etc. - I've not seen that article which is very thorough.

Answer (score 4):

Wild guess, but could be `hasLayout`.

Try adding something like:

```
#tabs {
  zoom: 1;
}
```

Comment: Indeed. The evils of hasLayout will be repealed in IE8 standards mode, we are assured.

Comment: I had a quick look and it appears the #tabs div already hasLayout=true ... though I'm going to try applying zoom: 1 to the dynamic form that's displayed above, which I believe does not currently have hasLayout=true.